# Calculate last modified date for a specific sheet and start on row 2

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm using this script and it works great, except for two things:

1. it works on all sheets, and I'd like it to only work on a specified sheet.
2. it overwrites my header row, and I'd rather it start on the second row

Script:

```
function onEdit() {
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() != 11 ) { //checks the column
        var row = r.getRow();
        var time = new Date();
        time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "CST", "yyyy-MM-dd");
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('P' + row.toString()).setValue(time);//Enters date in Column P    
    };
};
```

Comment: I figured out part of it will keep working on it.

Comment: function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  if( r.getColumn() != 11 ) { //checks the column
     var row = r.getRow();
     var headerRows = 1;  // # header rows to ignore
  if (r.getRow() <= headerRows) return;
    var time = new Date();
    time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "CST", "yyyy-MM-dd");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('P' + row.toString()).setValue(time);//Enters date in Column P
    
  };
 };

Answer (score 0):

I figured out part of it. HOW TO SKIP THE FIRST ROW (HEADER ROW) The second part should be a little easier. added the following:

```
var headerRows = 1;  // # header rows to ignore
if (r.getRow() <= headerRows) return;
```

FULL SCRIPT:

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  if( r.getColumn() != 11 ) { //checks the column
    var row = r.getRow();
    var headerRows = 1;  // # header rows to ignore
    if (r.getRow() <= headerRows) return;

    var time = new Date();
    time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "CST", "yyyy-MM-dd");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('P' + row.toString()).setValue(time);//Enters date in Column P
  };
};
```